# Best practices for mapping structure members in an Ada-C binding application

Tags: c, struct, ada

In an Ada-C binding application where the structures(records) need to be passed and read/written between functions defined in C and Ada, what is the best way to declare structers at C and Ada side to ensure correct mapping of members between both the languages. For an example, I declared a structure in C (without using **bit fields** here), but at Ada side while declaring the same structures(record in Ada) I also used **use** representation clause to map it bitwise and then used the Convention C pragma. What I saw is that Ada was not reading the structure properly which probably I reckon could be because of wrong bitwise mapping of members.

Just wanted to know what is the best way to ensure correct declaration of same structure at Ada and C side. Should at the C side, the structure be declared using **bit fields** and then use the same bit scheme to decalre the same structure/record at Ada side using **use** representation clause?

For Example in C,

```
/* Position Data Structure */
typedef struct {
    float lat;
    float lon;
} POSITION_TYPE;

/* Fix Data Structure */
typedef struct {
    int32_t fix_id;
    char fix_type[20];
    char leg_type[7];
    char ident[8];
    char ident_code[11];
    char fix_descriptor[30];
    char way_ident[7];
    char ref_pt[8];
    char ref_pt_code[11];
    POSITION_TYPE position;
} FIX_DATA_TYPE;
```

I declared the same structure in Ada as:

```
  -- Position Record --------------------------------------------------------
  type Pos_Rec_Type is
    record
      Lat : C.C_float;
      Lon : C.C_float;
    end record;

    for Pos_Rec_Type use
      record
        Lat at 0 range  0..31;
        Lon at 0 range 32..63;
      end record;

   pragma Convention (Convention => C, Entity => Pos_Rec_Type);

  -- Fix Data Record --------------------------------------------------------
  type Fix_Data_Rec_Type is
    record
      Fix_Id              : C.int;
      Fix_Type            : C.char_array(1..20);
      Leg_Type            : C.char_array(1..7);
      Ident               : C.char_array(1..8);
      Ident_Code          : C.char_array(1..11);
      Fix_Desc            : C.char_array(1..30);
      Way_Ident           : C.char_array(1..7);
      Ref_Pt              : C.char_array(1..8);
      Ref_Pt_Code         : C.char_array(1..11);
      Position            : Pos_Rec_Type;
   end record;

    for Fix_Data_Rec_Type use
      record
        Fix_Id              at 0 range   0..31;
        Fix_Type            at 0 range  32..191;
        Leg_Type            at 0 range 192..247;
        Ident               at 0 range 248..311;
        Ident_Code          at 0 range 312..399;
        Fix_Desc            at 0 range 400..639;
        Way_Ident           at 0 range 640..695;
        Ref_Pt              at 0 range 696..759;
        Ref_Pt_Code         at 0 range 760..847;
        Position            at 0 range 848..911;
      end record;

   pragma Convention (Convention => C, Entity => Fix_Data_Rec_Type);
```

But when I populated this structure at Ada side and transferred it to C functions, I saw that the position record was not decoded correctly. When I disabled the representation clause for **Fix_Data_Rec_Type**, it worked properly.

Comment: IIRC using convention C with representation clauses may lead to strange behaviors - get rid of convention C [if you use rep clauses you shouldn't need convention C anyway]. To be honest, I wrote many bindings to C, and almost never used Convention C with records.
Watch out for types of fields.

Comment: @darkestkhan, if I use representation clauses at Ada side only, do I need to use bit fields at C side to declare the structure?

Comment: @darkestkhan, Also then what is the application using pragma C convention and why is it not a good idea to use here?

Comment: Adding a MCVE would probably encourage better answers.

Comment: And I think you've also answered it yourself.  `Convention C` alone works, allowing the compiler to pick the same rep on both sides (which I was going to suggest). Adding a Rep clause overrides that, forcing the Ada compiler to follow your choice - but there's no way for that to influence the C compiler. So if you must use a rep clause, either you *really* need to know how the C compiler works, or you need to explicitly specify the same alignment on the C side. (You might find this rep clause matches the C choice when compiled with -m32 for example, or some older revision of the compiler)

Answer (score 3):

If you use `-gnatR` to print representation info for types, you’ll find that

with rep clause:

```
for Pos_Rec_Type'Size use 64;
for Pos_Rec_Type'Alignment use 4;
for Pos_Rec_Type use record
   Lat at 0 range  0 .. 31;
   Lon at 4 range  0 .. 31;
end record;

for Fix_Data_Rec_Type'Object_Size use 928;
for Fix_Data_Rec_Type'Value_Size use 912;
for Fix_Data_Rec_Type'Alignment use 4;
for Fix_Data_Rec_Type use record
   Fix_Id      at   0 range  0 .. 31;
   Fix_Type    at   4 range  0 .. 159;
   Leg_Type    at  24 range  0 .. 55;
   Ident       at  31 range  0 .. 63;
   Ident_Code  at  39 range  0 .. 87;
   Fix_Desc    at  50 range  0 .. 239;
   Way_Ident   at  80 range  0 .. 55;
   Ref_Pt      at  87 range  0 .. 63;
   Ref_Pt_Code at  95 range  0 .. 87;
   Position    at 106 range  0 .. 63;
end record;
```

without rep clause:

```
for Pos_Rec_Type'Size use 64;
for Pos_Rec_Type'Alignment use 4;
for Pos_Rec_Type use record
   Lat at 0 range  0 .. 31;
   Lon at 4 range  0 .. 31;
end record;

for Fix_Data_Rec_Type'Size use 928;
for Fix_Data_Rec_Type'Alignment use 4;
for Fix_Data_Rec_Type use record
   Fix_Id      at   0 range  0 .. 31;
   Fix_Type    at   4 range  0 .. 159;
   Leg_Type    at  24 range  0 .. 55;
   Ident       at  31 range  0 .. 63;
   Ident_Code  at  39 range  0 .. 87;
   Fix_Desc    at  50 range  0 .. 239;
   Way_Ident   at  80 range  0 .. 55;
   Ref_Pt      at  87 range  0 .. 63;
   Ref_Pt_Code at  95 range  0 .. 87;
   Position    at 108 range  0 .. 63;
end record;
```

With the rep clause, the `Position` component is in fact misaligned (106 isn’t divisible by 4).

Comment: -gnatR looks useful!